# How do I lock a growing directory in memory?

Tags: linux, tmpfs

I want a directory to be fast to read from, like on tmpfs for some time.

The closest thing is this:

```
vmtouch -L -m 2G /path/to/mydir
```

But this does not detect new or deleted files.

Comment: Maybe you wand anything-sync-daemon, it uses an overlay between your data and a tmpfs
Your data is in a tmpfs, and is efficiently synced back to the hdd (only whats changed). The kernel has support for the overlay filesystem, anything-sync-daemon mounts a tmpfs and your dir in the overlay, it then efficiently syncs back changes (thanks to the overlayfs). This might be helpful:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Anything-sync-daemon#What_is_overlayfs_and_why_do_I_want_to_use_it.3F

Answer (score 0):

Implemented workaround: https://gist.github.com/vi/77717d7076618af92344

Mirrored here:

```
#!/bin/bash

# vmtouchpoll: Keep some files locked in memory (including new files, dropping deleted files)

# Usage: vmtouchpoll '/path/to/some/files/*.idx'

# Works by periodically restarting vmtouch with a new set of files
# Implemented by Vitaly "_Vi" Shukela in 2015, License=MIT


F=($(eval echo $1))

vmtouch -L -m 2G "${F[@]}"&
P1=$!
P2=0
disown

trap 'kill $P1; [[ $P2 -gt 0 ]] && kill $P2' EXIT

while true; do
    sleep 55;
    F=($(eval echo $1))

    vmtouch -q -L -m 2G "${F[@]}"&
    P2=$!
    disown

    sleep 5;
    kill $P1
    P1=$P2
    P2=0
done
```